# Unity in-app purchases (IAP) always call ProcessPurchase but order is refunded

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

This case is user via untiy IAP to buy product,and user refunded this order by google play.

But when user restart game and init store, unity IAP will call "ProcessPurchase" method to process not exist order each time.It"s been a day and nerver stop this ProcessPurchase, so user always show error dialogue "(product name) purchasing failed". Is there any reason for this to happen?

unity IAP version is 4.1.3

Comment: It's always nice to fully spell out an acronym on the first use.  Otherwise dummies like me have to go Googling... :)

Comment: I'm sorry for that,Thanks for edit